# Cannot create admin users in separate databases in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, security, authorization

I'm using MongoDB version 2.6.2 and have two databases - admin and books.
In previous versions of MongoDB (1.*) I could create admin users for each database separately. Now whenever I try to create users for second db, they're still added to the first one.
Here is the excerpt from the mongo shell output:

```
/* creating admin db */
> use admin;
switched to db admin
> db.createUser( { "user" : "admin_root", "pwd": "pass", "roles" : ["root"] } )
Successfully added user: { "user" : "admin_root", "roles" : [ "root" ] }

/* creating books db */
> use books;
switched to db books
> db.createUser( { "user" : "admin_books", "pwd": "pass", "roles" : ["dbOwner"] } )
Successfully added user: { "user" : "admin_books", "roles" : [ "dbOwner" ] }
> db.createUser( { "user" : "logger", "pwd": "pass", "roles" : ["readWrite"] } )
Successfully added user: { "user" : "logger", "roles" : [ "readWrite" ] }

/* users in books db */
> db.system.users.find()
> /* Nothing here */

/* users in admin db */
> use admin
switched to db admin
> db.system.users.find()
{ "_id" : "admin.admin_root", "user" : "admin_root", "db" : "admin", "credentials" : { "MONGODB-CR" : "082e4c55ecb7993eb3b1825fe7df8902" }, "roles" : [ { "role" : "root", "db" : "admin" } ] }
{ "_id" : "books.admin_books", "user" : "admin_books", "db" : "books", "credentials" : { "MONGODB-CR" : "0384574df69c4b809c4432f79c0d8a97" }, "roles" : [ { "role" : "dbOwner", "db" : "books" } ] }
{ "_id" : "books.logger", "user" : "logger", "db" : "books", "credentials" : { "MONGODB-CR" : "307b0eac760bd1031b82908c84a231d6" }, "roles" : [ { "role" : "readWrite", "db" : "books" } ] }
>
```

Is there anything I'm doing wrong?

Comment: what makes you think something is wrong?

Comment: @AsyaKamsky well I expected that I'll be able to add a database admin that could manage its database users. It seems that now I have to manage them from admin db.

Comment: you did add that user - into admin DB which is how 2.6 handles it.

Comment: @AsyaKamsky this is probably an offtopic, but do I need to grant any extra priveleges to admin_books user? Because if I try to query db.system.users with it, when authentication is enabled, I'm getting "QueryFailure flag was not authorized for query on books.system.users".

Comment: did you authenticate as the correct user (against admin db? or against the db you are querying?)

Comment: I authenticated against db I'm querying (as an admin_books user). I wanted this guy to own books database and manage its users. Should I authenticate agains admin db, since this is where all users are stored?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is correct behavior. The users are being created with the correct credentials and roles for their assigned databases. For instance this document in the "system.users" collection in the database admin:

```
{ "_id" : "books.admin_books", "user" : "admin_books", "db" : "books", "credentials" : { "MONGODB-CR" : "0384574df69c4b809c4432f79c0d8a97" }, "roles" : [ { "role" : "dbOwner", "db" : "books" } ] }
```

clearly shows that this user has the role "dbOwner" for the database "books".

Perhaps your confusion is that all of these users are stored in the "system.users" collection in the "admin" database. That is where all user information is stored. From the documentation:

> **admin.system.users**
>
> Changed in version 2.6.
>
> The admin.system.users collection stores the user’s authentication
>   credentials as well as any roles assigned to the user. Users may
>   define authorization roles in the admin.system.roles collection.

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/system-collections/